# share prefilled text on facebook via android app

Tags: android, android-facebook

I have tried to share some pre-filled text to facebook from my android app .
But i am unable to do that.
Is there any way to share some pre-filled text in the facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot share prefilled text to Facebook.The share dialog however will share  a link for you and you have the option to manually write the text and then post along with the link.
You can check [This Link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423) for reference.Also see the [Facebook Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

So basically you can share a link and comment on it.

Comment: Isn't there any way like using facebook api, facebook graph api ?? @Anirudh Sharma

Comment: nope it's not possible.The share dialog can share only a link for you with a comment that you'll have to write.It's their policy.

Comment: @imon Yes anirudh is correct. Link is mandatory while sending text. This is implemented for security purposes.